# How to use strings.Contains on an interface

Tags: go, interface, contains

I am receiving a panic on the following line of code. `interface conversion: interface {} is []string, not string`

My interface is a map of strings. What is the best method to find whether the figure interface contains a specific string.

```
if strings.Contains(figure["figure1"].(string), "one"){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your type assertion is wrong, you are trying to access a value from a key on your interface, which hasn't been accessed as a map, so this can't work as the `interface{}` isn't indexible.

What you have to do instead is to cast your whole interface to a `map[string]string` like such

```
stringMap, ok := interfaceArg.(map[string]string)
if !ok {
    return errors.New("cast failed")
}

if strings.Contains(stringMap["figure1"], "one") {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Invalid type assertion (non-interface type map[string]interface {} on left), how is this possible?

Comment: Apparently you are doing an invalid type assertion. You can only do `.(type)` on an `interface{}` and you are apparently trying to do it on a `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: If that's the case, you should do `interf, ok := mapInterface[key]` followed by `value, ok := interf.(string)` if the value you want to get from the `interface{}` is a string. If it can contain multiple values, you can do a switch on the interface type: `switch interf.(type)`

Comment: Let me know if that helps!